# How to append [Op.or] to an object in NodeJS to build up where condition for Sequelize?

Tags: node.js, javascript-objects

In my NodeJS model, I have the following query.

```
Ad.adList = function(where_condition, lang_code='EN') {
    return this.findAll({
          attributes:['id','name'],
          where: where_condition,
          include:[
            { 
                association : 'ad_user', 
                where       : {status:'a', is_ban:'n', deleted_at:null}, 
                required    : true
            },
            { association: 'translation', where: {lang_code:lang_code} ,required: false},
            { association: 'ad_title', where: {status:'a', deleted_at:null} ,required: false}
          ],
          order: [
            ['translation', 'name', 'asc']
          ]
    });
};
```

In the controller file, I build up the where_condition object like this:-

```
let where_condition_Obj =   {};
                
if(typeof formData.show_active !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.show_active !== null && formData.show_active !== '')
{
    where_condition_Obj.status = 'a';
}
if(typeof formData.category_id !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.category_id !== null && formData.category_id !== '')
{
    where_condition_Obj.category = formData.category_id;
}
```

As such, the where_condition_Obj object in the controller becomes like this:-

```
where_condition_Obj =   {
                    status      : 'a',
                    category    : 1,
                }
```

Now I need to run an OR query with like operation. For such case, my where_condition_Obj should be like this

```
where_condition_Obj =   {
                        status      : 'a',
                        category    : 1,
                        [Op.or]     : [
                                    { 
                                        name: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        description: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }   
                                ]
                }
```

But how can I append [Op.or] in an object like this `where_condition_Obj.category = formData.category_id;`

I tried something like

```
where_condition_Obj.[Op.or] = [
                                    { 
                                        name: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        description: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }   
                                ]
```

But it gives me error. Is there any way by which this can be achieved?

Note: I could have initialize the object like this from beginning,

```
where_condition_Obj =   {
                        [Op.or]     : [
                                    { 
                                        name: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }, 
                                    {
                                        description: 
                                        { 
                                            [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
                                        }
                                    }   
                                ]
                }
```

but I don't want to do this because this condition would be appended only based on a particular parameter which may or may not be sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `where_condition` as `Op.and` with an array of conditions like:

```
[Op.and]: [{
 status: 'a' 
}, {
  category: 1,
}]
```

And afterwards on some condition you can just push a new condition into this array:

```
where_condition[Op.and].push = {
  [Op.or]: [
     { 
       name: 
        { 
          [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
        }
     }, 
     {
       description: 
        { 
          [Op.like] : '%' + searchText + '%'
        }
      }   
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this condition today, after researching for a few minutes I got some basic idea of how to make this thing work.

Below is my approach which worked for me.

Declare another object for the `OR` condition.

```
let where_condition_Obj = {};
let or_condition_Obj = {};
```

For the normal `where` condition, do it like the way you have done.
Eg:

```
if (typeof formData.show_active !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.show_active !== null && formData.show_active !== '') {
      where_condition_Obj.status = 'a';
}

if (typeof formData.category_id !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.category_id !== null && formData.category_id !== '') {
      where_condition_Obj.category = 1;
}
```

For the `OR` condition follow below approach

```
if (typeof formData.name !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.name !== null && formData.name !== '') {
     or_condition_Obj.name = { [Op.substring]: 'name' }
}

if (typeof formData.description !== 'undefined' && userIdformData.description !== null && formData.description !== '') {
     or_condition_Obj.description = { [Op.substring]: 'description' }
}
```

And finally in your `where` condition get both those objects and assign it like below.

```
where: {
    [Op.or]: or_condition_Obj,
    [Op.and]: where_condition_Obj
}
```